# Different colors in different plot points in line chart

Tags: android

I am using MpAndroidChart library to draw a line chart. I have a single LineDataSet with multiple entry points. We can customize the circle color of the LineDataSet but I need different colors for different plot points. How can we achieve this ?

Comment: can you put Image of your charts?

Comment: Here is the link for the image.  https://imgur.com/a/dxyL7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below code to set different colors for circles:

```
lineDataSet.setCircleColors(new int[]{Color.BLUE,Color.RED,Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE,Color.RED,Color.GREEN});
```

Here I am using six colors because my chart has six values. So number of colors should be according to the number of chart values.